# Generating search suggestions as data is typed into the input field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to generate suggestions using data in a database without refreshing the page as a user types some data in the input field below. AJAX is quite new to me and I have been trying to figure out where I went wrong for quite some time now. It seems as if the code below is not returning any results at all. I appreciate any help.

My markup:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search(searchword) {
      $('#suggestion').load('invoice-get-data.php?searchword=' + searchword);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="prod-name">
    <!-- As user input data, call search function, and narrow down results on every keystore -->
    <input onKeyPress="search(this.value)" type="text" id="prod-name"/>
    <div id="suggestion"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

AJAX so far:

```
<?php   
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword');

    if(!$conn){
        die('Error: Unable to connect.' . '<br>' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn);

    $searchword = $_GET['searchword'];

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod-name LIKE '$searchword'") or die(mysql_error());


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        echo $row['prod-name'] . '<br/>';
    }


?>
```

Comment: You need quotes around `$searchword`, but most importantly, you must protect your code against SQL injections. You should use Mysqli or PDO, instead of the deprecated mysql library. Read http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added quotes, but it is still not working.

Comment: If you're in Chrome, use the Console (F12), right-click it and enable "Log XMLHttpRequest". Then tell us what you're getting.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about console using f12! great advice! thank you!

Comment: Now it is returning results but the pattern matching isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starters, the "onchange" event doesn't fire until a textbox has lost focus (meaning the cursor goes out of the textbox). You are probably looking for a keyboard event like onkeyup or onkeypress.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed to onKeyPress, but it is still not working and not returning any results.

Comment: open your developer tools (usually f12) and go to the console to view any ajax calls to see what is being sent to/from the server.

Comment: +1 Did not know about console using f12! great advice! thank you!